# About javaMe RSA and AES

Tags: java-me

Does anybody know any good libraries in order to perform RSA and AES cryptographic operations in javaME?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/). It includes a lightweight cryptography API for Java.